# Error:Project 'app' not found in root project 'ProjectName'

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

So I tried to clone a project from Github. 
First thing I did was go to Project Structure > Modules > + > Import Module and selected build.gradle, it added 2 modules ProjectName(root module) and :app. 
Then I pressed Sync Project with Gradle Files after wich I got the error: Project 'app' not found in root project 'ProjectName'.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 10):

This is late response but replying for those who found your question from google search and need help with this error :)

Check settings.gradle (Project Settings)
and check below code

```
include ':app'
```

'app' must be your root project

Comment: do you mean add that line to the file?

Comment: android/settings.gradle

Comment: What do you mean though?

Answer (score 1):

I've come across Gradle having this issue with older projects that were of the structure:

```
project
|-src
```

Newer projects would be:

```
project
|-app
  |-src
```

I'm still looking into what changed in the gradle plugin that causes it to automatically look for 'app' now.